# Initial Deployment-MDT+WDS

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, wds, imaging, mdt

So I've been attempting to use Microsoft Deployment Toolkit with Windows Deployment Services to deploy images on a client. The deployment server is running Server 2012 and is both the Domain Controller and the deployment server. I am able to import Windows 7 enterprise, office 2013, some drivers, etc. Then I added a task sequence according to this article:

http://prajwaldesai.com/deploying-windows-7-using-microsoft-deployment-toolkit-part-1/

Most of the process of setting up the deployment share was either the same or very similar to that article.

Now, when I PXE boot to the right image on the deployment share, I get a prompt to login, etc. Eventually I come to a task sequence page, where, in order to continue, I must select a task sequence to execute. Only no task sequences appear. I checked back in MDT, and the task sequence is there and enabled. The task is supposed to format the hard drive and install windows 7.

So I was wondering, as I am still quite new and inexperienced with MDT+WAIK+WDS, is this task sequence supposed to be hidden?

I read a few forum threads about task sequences which had previously been visible suddenly dissapearing, but that doesn't seem to describe my problem.

Also, I tried deleting the task sequence and creating a new one, but the same issue occured. I also noticed that the Task Sequence ID of 001 was no longer available. Are these IDs only one-time uses per deployment share?

This domain is a small cluster of computers set up specifically to test this deployment solution to see if it would be appropriate to implement for the entire lab, so any other solutions which might be appropriate would be appreciated. The goal is to deploy images of windows 7 with standard applications. Every year this image is rebuilt with updated applications and re-captured using Ghost, which we are trying to ditch. Being able to re-create the image using MDT would make things a lot easier, and would increase flexibility if, for example, I had to add an application in after the image has been deployed.

---

So another update, I apologize, but I keep hitting my head against the wall trying to figure this out.

I still am unable to see the Install OS Task Sequence when I PXE boot the client. In MDT I have 4 task sequences, each performing a specific function. It seems like I can see any task sequence which does not deploy an OS. So I have a sequence which wipes the disk, installs windows, installs office, and then syspreps and captures the image. Only I am unable to run the OS Deployment TS in the LTI image. Everything I am running is 64 bit, so I do not believe architecture mismatch is the problem, and in MDT the TSs are enabled and visible. Deployment share is updated and is unrestricted in terms of permissions. The client now has a completely empty, unformatted hard drive. Does anyone know why this task sequence won't show up?

In MDT under the components tab WAIK still isn't listed under "Installed", but it is listed under "Downloaded". I have reinstalled, refreshed, rebooted, etc. But WAIK still doesn't seem to want to be listed as Installed. I googled this, and several other users have this issue, but MDT still seems to work fine, so I'm not convinced that's the problem, or if it is, its not all of the problem.

Again, I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: You must update the deployment share in DeploymentWorkbench: right-click on the deployment share object below Deployment Shares, and click Update Deployment Share; although I'm not using 2012.  Check [this out](http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2010/03/11/deploy-windows-7-the-easy-way-using-wds-mdt-and-aik-step-by-step-video.aspx).

Comment: The server share was updated, several times. I even deleted the images and re-created them from scratch. Could this be a WAIK thing? I have it installed in Windows, but it doesn't appear to be recognized in the workbench, as in I don't see it in the installed section of the components branch on the tree.

Comment: What do you have listed in `Deployment Workbench\Information Center\Components`? Did you verify your WIM image(s) using some method?  You are obviously not speaking of the boot images pushed via PXE, correct?  In my `DeploymentWorkbench\MDT Deployment Share\Task Sequences`, what do you have listed?  In the `WDS` console, you will not see anything under `Install Images`, but the winpe images will be listed in `WDS` under `Boot Images`.  What do or don't you see?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain that very well. I do have two PXE boot images, one one x64 and one x86. I've played around with the task sequences, and so right now I have one which is supposed to sysprep and capture, and another which is supposed to install office. However, before I deleted it, I also had one which was supposed to install Windows 7 after formatting the hard drive. That task sequence doesn't show up, and nor does the sysprep and capture sequence. The install office, however, does. I can't check the components right now, but I'll post back later when I can.

Comment: Changed around the task sequences, I'll try it and post back with the results.

Comment: @kevin You didn't mention architecture for your OS or boot images... If you boot to a 64 bit boot image, you will not see task sequences for 32 bit OS installations, however if you boot into a 32 bit boot image, you should see task sequences for both 32 bit and 64 bit OS installs.

Comment: @WinOutreach4, Sorry, its all 64 bit. the client is running on an Intel Xeon, 8 GB RAM. I think the deploy OS Task Sequence isn't showing up because the disk already has an image on it. So I created a Task Sequence to wipe the drive, and then I would be able to run the Install windows TS. Only when I ran the Wipe Disk TS, I got another error: Litetouch deployment failed, return code = -2147023504 0x80070570. A Google search told me I had some missing or corrupt files. This seems weird as I'm just wiping the disk, but I'll import 7 again and rebuild the image to make sure. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I got it to work, and I think I know why. So in this test domain, I had three computers. One was the DC server with WDS, DHCP,DNS, ADDS, etc. running. The second was a machine with MDT, WAIK running for making the images, and the third was a test machine for deploying the images on. The deployment share was on the server, and I stupidly had not changed the permissions on that specific folder to make it a share. Changed that and now it seems to be working.

Comment: `REMINST` is required to be shared.  I ran into this problem, as I use `truecrypt` to encrypt my data partition, needing mounting after boot, then I forgot to share `REMINST` == failure.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try on Monday. Would that block the OS install and not the application install? Because I was still able to kick off the application install, just not the OS install. Of course the application install never finished because there was no OS installed, but I was still able to see the task sequence which deployed the application.

Comment: Let me know how it goes.  In regards to your comment: How are you installing the application?  Streamlined into the a task sequence (which first installs the OS, then installs the app)?  I don't really understand what you're saying (which is basically "I'm installing an app on a non-existing OS").  Have you isolated task sequences for app installs only?  You can check if an OS exists and fail if it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, figured it out. And now I feel like an idiot because it was an architecture mismatch. I thought I had imported a 64 bit version of Windows 7, but by accident I picked up a 32 bit DVD. I think there is a way to enable 32 bit OSs in a 64 bit environment in WDS, but I haven't done that yet.

Comment: @kevin All it should take is to boot to the LiteTouchPE_x86.wim boot image instead of the LiteTouchPE_x64.wim boot image and that will show both 32 bit and 64 bit task sequences and allow you to install either architecture on the machine. I am glad to hear that you resolved your initial issue.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, MDT creates two boot images: a 32-bit boot image and a 64-bit boot image. You must use the 32-bit boot image to deploy 32-bit operating systems, and you must use the 64-bit boot image to deploy 64-bit operating systems.

When you mismatch the bit-width of the boot image with respect to the bit-width of the operating system that you are trying to deploy (e.g., booting from a 32-bit boot image but trying to deploy 64-bit Windows 10), MDT hides the mismatched bit-width's task sequences from you automatically.